# iPhone SdK: AVPlayer will not play a composition after adding a audio track

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder, avplayer, avurlasset, avmutablecomposition

After adding an audio track (recorded with AVAudioRecorder) to a composition AVPlayer will not play it. AVPlayer.status = 1 and AVPlayer.error = null.

I have looked at the WWDC10 AVEdit demo code and it's pretty much similar. Could it be an audio format incompatibility?

the original composition allready contains a video and audio track from a video asset.

after removing the newly added audio track the player still does not play
after removing the original audio track the player **will** play.

I'm also finding it hard to get debug information that would point me to the problem. If anyone has a suggestion it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for adding the audio track

any help is most welcome

Jean-Pierre

```
-(void)editAudioViewController:(EditAudioViewController *)editAudioViewController didEditAudio:(NSURL *)url
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

BOOL result;
NSError * error = nil;

if (url)
{
    AVURLAsset * asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil] ;

    CMTimeRange audioTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero , asset.duration);
    if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(CMTimeRangeGetEnd(audioTimeRange), >, [composition duration]))
        audioTimeRange.duration = CMTimeSubtract([composition duration], audioTimeRange.start);

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack *audioTrack = [asset compatibleTrackForCompositionTrack:compositionAudioTrack];

    result = [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioTimeRange.duration) ofTrack:audioTrack atTime:audioTimeRange.start error:&error];

    if (!result)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    }

    [mp replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition]];
    [mp seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two separate sessions in my audio recorder code one for recording and one for playback.
I switched to a single record/play session and this somehow fixed the problem:

```
audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

if (!audioSession.inputIsAvailable)
{
    NSLog(@"No input available");
}

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

NSError * error = nil;

[audioSession setActive:TRUE error:&error];

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}
```